# how to solve 'start' error command on .bat file

Tags: windows, batch-file

I wanna open a web page by batch file commands. So I have created a .bat like this:

```
start http://www.website.com
```

So the default browser should open this url.
But an error appears:

```
The parameter is incorrect
```

I don't know why it's happening.
Also I'm using windows 10.

Comment: can't replicate. Working fine here.

Comment: Use a valid URL and see if that works. This is wrong and an invalid address (although some browsers may accept it) `http://www.website.com` and this is right `http:\\www.website.com`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to select the browser you will use, for example:

`start iexplore.exe http://www.website.com`
or
`start chrome.exe http://www.website.com`

Comment: For me it works, even without the browser...try:
`start "" http://www.website.com`